# Use SFINAE to enable method if tuple is large enough

Tags: c++

I have a class that holds a tuple:

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct Point {
    std::tuple<Args...> data;
    ... 
};
```

Internally, I want some methods that create views of the data. For instance, when the data has 1 or more dimension, then it is nice to have methods called `x` and `y` which pull off the first and second elements:

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct Point {

    std::tuple<Args...> data;

    using value_type = decltype(data);

    template<typename T = typename std::tuple_element<0, value_type>::type>
    T &x() {
        return std::get<0>(data);
    }

    template<typename T = typename std::tuple_element<1, value_type>::type>
    T &y() {
        return std::get<1>(data);
    }
};
```

The issue is the tuple size. I can't figure out how I would use SFINAE to not provide this method when the tuple size is less than than the accessor. For instance, the above class works beautifully if you create Points with more than 1 dimension (e.g. `Point<float,int>`). However, the code will not compile if you try to create a `Point<float>`. Specifically, with GCC 8.2, I am getting the compiler error:

```
no type named 'type' in 'struct std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<float> >'
```

I also tried idioms like this:

```
auto y() -> typename std::tuple_element<1, value_type>::type {
    return std::get<1>(data);
}
```

but I get the same compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "S" in SFINAE stands for "substitution". Therefore you need to ensure that your check happens during substitution time. You can do this by introducing an extra template parameter defaulted to `value_type`:

```
template<typename U = value_type, typename T = typename std::tuple_element<0, U>::type>
T &x() {
    return std::get<0>(data);
}

template<typename U = value_type, typename T = typename std::tuple_element<1, U>::type>
T &y() {
    return std::get<1>(data);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xNnygI)

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, you might "discard" method thanks to `requires`:

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct Point {

    std::tuple<Args...> data;

    decltype(auto) x() requires (sizeof...(Args) > 0) { return std::get<0>(data); }
    decltype(auto) y() requires (sizeof...(Args) > 1) { return std::get<1>(data); }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37566223ce896a82)